# Open Trip Planner Version(0.11.x) Grizzly Server Error

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, transport

i've a problem with Grizzly Server, run successfully 'mvn clean package'

```
[INFO] OpenTripPlanner .................................... SUCCESS [  0.066 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner Leaflet Client ..................... SUCCESS [  0.815 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner Core ............................... SUCCESS [ 15.629 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner REST API Servlet ................... SUCCESS [  4.179 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner OpenLayers Client .................. SUCCESS [  1.527 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner Analyst Client ..................... SUCCESS [  0.076 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner Administration Client .............. SUCCESS [  0.312 s]

[INFO] OpenTripPlanner Municipal Boundary Reverse Geocoder  SUCCESS [  0.822 s]
```

and than created my Graph.obj perfectly.

I used this documentation: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/17Q8zxmnqQIQGBK7BL7iYrxWeEJQoII9UO4cpNTAxlCw/edit#heading=h.dsf84r8z5okd

But, when i try to run this code*(start server)* :

```
bash otp -a -g /Users/username/documents/MYOTPworkspace/ -s
```

I get following error:

```
ERROR (OTPMain.java:81) An uncaught ContainerException occurred inside OTP. Restarting server.
```

My Version : Maven **3.3.9**
My Java Version: **1.8.0_65**

I've already edited my `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Target Java versions -->
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Could you please help me? 
How can i get rid of this error? 
Thanks in advance.